# Is there an easy way to use a JSON layout in Rails 3.1 for `render json: {}`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to specify a layout for rendering JSON in Rails 3.1+ (not that I found any easy way to do it in any previous version of Rails)?

I've been using a helper like this:

```
def render_as_json(obj, status = 200, *args)
  render(inline: obj.to_json(*args), layout: 'default', status: status)
end
```

It doesn't seem like `render json: obj` will render a layout.

I just wanted to have some metadata in the layout file:

```
<%- @content = yield -%>
{
  "data":<%= @content.present? ? raw(@content) : '{}' %>,
  "metadata":<%= raw(json_layout_metadata.to_json) %>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old now but I was trying to use a JSON layout and an XML layout and while searching I found your question and it helped me somehow solve my problem so here is what I did for the JSON part and the XML is pretty much the same:

Create a template file in the layout folder in your application(in the same directory of application.html.erb), call it anything but make its extension ".json.erb", let's assume you named it "json_layout.json.erb". Put in it whatever constant content you want to add and in the place you want to display dynamic data put a

```
<%= yield %>
```

In my case, this is my template:

```
{"status": <%= response.status %>,"data": <%= yield %>}
```

Now in your controller where you want to display JSON use the following format in the respond_to block:

```
format.json { render :inline => @the_object.to_json(any_additional_options) , :layout => "json_layout.json.erb" }
```

Just be careful in case of XML to put in the options of the to_xml method

```
:skip_instruct => true
```

as you would probably don't need the full XML generated by default because you add your own in the layout.